# What does (Object) do in java?

Tags: java

I watched a tutorial on 2D game engine design in YouTube and there is this line:

```
private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

I know that the pixels are supposed to contain integer list of colors for the image but I don't understand how the data of the pixels got into the image since in the tutorial this is the only line where pixels are used.

So is (DataBufferInt) means I am connecting pixels to the data of type DataBufferInt in the image?

Comment: You are casting to DataBufferInt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called **casting**. The object (which had a different runtime type) will be considered as the new given type.

Say, that `image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()` returns a type `DataBuffer`. But in reality (the runtime type) it is `DataBufferInt`.

Your `DataBuffer` type does not have a `getData()` method, that would return `int[]`. So, you need to *tell the compiler* that it is a `DataBufferInt`, so you could get the data as `int[]`.

If the runtime data type is different, and you try to cast, you will get a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Which, in turn, allows access to (accessible) fields and methods of the new type.

Comment: Actually, it better had the same (or an assignment-compatible) runtime type you are trying to cast it to. Otherwise you'll get an exception. The runtime type of an object cannot be changed. The cast just assigns a new compile-time type.

Comment: @Thilo I agree. The question here was about that certain piece of code. But casting is sometimes unavoidable in practice, especially if you are using some low-level libraries, like image manipulation.